Child state is not updating as expected
final class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count: Int = 0
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    @Binding var navigationStack: [CShareSteps]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent Count: \(model.count)")
            Button("Go to Child View") {
                navigationStack.append(.test($model.count))
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: CShareSteps.self) { step in
            switch step {
            case let .test(count):
                ChildView(count: count)
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Parent View")
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var count: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child Count: \(count)")
            Button("Increment") {
                count += 1
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Child View")
    }
}

enum CShareSteps: Steps {
    case test(Binding<Int>)
}

Child count is not updating until i move count from Model to View

Please show a [mcve], and explain what your goal is. What are you trying to do? Bindings are not supposed to be passed through a navigation path.

I hope you don't mind but I renamed a few things in your code. In SwiftUI ObservableObject is for models and View structs are view models.

You could try passing your viewModel to the ChildView().environmentObject(viewModel), and
declare @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ParentViewModel in ChildView()
and use viewModel.count directly.

@Sweeper you are correct. I tried with NavigationLink and its working now

I found out that it was Navigation Stack issue replacing it with NavigationLink fixed the issue. There are issues in NavigationStack when padding Binding to child views
